# Cordova plugin firebase sudden error in ionis 3

Tags: firebase, ionic3

I have error in cordova plugin firebase in ionic 3

BUILD FAILED in 38s

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   24 actionable tasks: 24 executed
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Note: E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:6: error: cannot find
>   symbol
>   import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
>                                 ^
>     symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceIdService
>     location: package com.google.firebase.iid
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:9: error: cannot find
>   symbol
>   public class FirebasePluginInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
>                                                        ^
>     symbol: class FirebaseInstanceIdService
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:544: error: method getByteArray in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
>                               : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getByteArray(key, namespace);
>                                                                   ^
>     required: String
>     found: String,String
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:562: error: method getValue in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
>                               : FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getValue(key, namespace);
>                                                                   ^
>     required: String
>     found: String,String
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:616: error: no suitable method found for setDefaults(Map,String)
>                           FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaultsToMap(defaults), namespace);
>                                                             ^
>       method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(Map) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       method FirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(int) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:780: error: cannot find symbol
>                           myTrace.incrementCounter(counterNamed);
>                                  ^
>     symbol:   method incrementCounter(String)
>     location: variable myTrace of type Trace
>   E:\ionic\School_App_A\School_App_A\School_App_A\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:18: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>       @Override
>       ^
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: i've the same issue :(    cordova 8.1.4, android 7.1.4, ionic3. This firebase plugin is driving me crazy for days

Comment: I have similar problem -> FirebasePlugin.java:436: error: cannot find symbol

Answer (score 2):

I am not an experienced person but try this solution it was work for me.

Go into your android platform directory and find for `string.xml` file, it is in `PROJECT_DIR\platforms\android\res\values` in my case so just need to correct this path inside `plugins\cordova-plugin-firebase` js file.

Here is what I did for my project and it works for me.

For Cordova installations, `MY_APP\plugins\cordova-plugin-firebase\scripts\after_prepare.js` should be set to `stringsXml: ANDROID_DIR + '/res/values/strings.xml'`

Build now, hopefully, it should work,

Answer (score 2):

cordova-plugin-firebase is not updated now with latest android support.

Pull request already in queue [issue](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/pull/1058).

Meanwhile you can you use :

```
ionic cordova platform rm android 
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
```

add

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase\#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue
```

Comment: So does setting up your config.xml with this fix it?
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase\#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue" />`

Comment: oh, this save my life !!!